# Retrieve database from MS Access and store it in javascript dataset

Tags: javascript, ms-access

I have a database in Microsoft Access something like this:
[image]

Now how to retrieve the data in MS Access and store it in the javascript dataset just like this:

```
var pivot_dataset = [
{"id": 34, "year": 2014 , "month": "JAN", "empName": "test", "empPos": "engineer", "numMc": 1, "numLeave": 2} 
];
```

Can someone help me with this please.

Comment: Related, if not duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777038/read-and-write-to-an-access-database-using-javascript

Comment: export to csv, open it in sublime text, Ctrl+Shift+L multiline edit adding "{},", 2 mins job.

Comment: @wayne really?can you guide me more please. im new to this.really appreciate it.

Comment: @RUJordan its not related,because I want to stroe it in the dataset. correct me if im wrong.

Comment: [sublime text](http://www.sublimetext.com/). It is practical, I don't know what else to write and guide you. search youtube "sublime text multiple cursors"