# Open .mdb from cloud

Tags: javascript, database, ms-access, hosting, google-drive-api

I have stored my .mdb file on google drive and host little website on it. Now I need to access that database but could not find any to do so as google drive does not provide php environment so suggest me any possible way

Answer (score 3):

Even if this IS possible, it's absolutely not going to be worth your time. You're better off finding a free/cheap hosting solution that supports some type of server-side scripting. Even if you do get it to work, you're going to have to make your database file read-write to the whole of the internet with NO authentication, and I'm not convinced even that will allow the type of access you need to connect to the database.

That said, here is some information that may help you out:

[How to Connect to SQL Server database from Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857670/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-database-from-javascript)

[Read and Write to an Access Database using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777038/read-and-write-to-an-access-database-using-javascript)

[Access to ODBC connected database (SQL Server) with Javascript](http://forums.asp.net/t/1285316.aspx?Access%20to%20odbc%20connected%20database%20SQL%20Server%20with%20javascript)

Again, I have to stress: PLEASE FIND ANOTHER WAY.